# How to log concurrent consumer thread states in Apache camel seda?

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I have a setup, one party is sending data, which is comes to seda endpoint with concurrent consumers defined as 10 in xml route defination, when the message is transformed, my guess is the message is picked up from queue by a thread and it starts working on it, when the message transformation is done, it sends the data to other party, other party responds to a different thread.

So, as other party is responding to diff thread, the first thread which sends the message, should not be blocked, it should be released.

I tried adding

```
.process(exchange->{
log.info("TH STATE {} "Thread.currentThread().getState();)
});
```

to all the code in above setup code, but the thread state is always runnable not even running,
is there any in Apache camel to log the cocurrent consumers seda threads in route definations in XML? or any other in-built class that can help?

Comment: What you try to do/achieve is really unclear, would you mind clarifying a bit more?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, I can't put code snippet as it is organizations code, but here is a sitaution, I have a seda endpoint with concurrent consumers, this consumer picks up a message from internal blocking queue right? once this consumer/thread sends this message to another endpoint, I want the thread to be available immediately for other message, but it seems to be blocked for 4-5 sec, I am checking if there is a timeout setting, for which thread is waiting, but in meanwhile I wanted to know is there any setting available with Apache camel seda, which will make thread not blocked?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, I will try to add some psuedo code.